# Why JPA/Hibernate behaves differently on windows and linux?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have developed a project on windows machine, I set Hibernate's hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to update. My entity name is Kullanici, so Hibernate creates kullanici table on windows machine.

I built the project and deployed war on Tomcat server running on Centos. When I run the project it gives error. Hibernate complaints no table named Kullanici. Because there exists kullanici table on db.

Any reason for this?

DB is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that the table was also created on Windows in lower case, `kullanici`, and you access it with upper case, `Kullanici`. Windows treats the names case-insensitive and that's why no error occurs on Windows.

On Centos, OTOH, names are referred case-sensitive - thus the error.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. Lowercase in both case, I am editing the question. so I have to state column names, explicitly. Thanks